# intel compilers, silence commandline warnings

Tags: c, compiler-warnings, intel, configure, icc

I just started building some code with the intel c compiler -- `icc`.  Our configure script likes to add the `-ffast-math` flag and maybe a couple others which seem to be GCC specific.  Invoking `icc` with `-ffast-math` produces the following warning which I would like to silence:

```
icc: command line warning #10006: ignoring unknown option '-ffast-math'
```

As far as I see it, there are 2 ways it could be silenced (But I'd love to see other solutions).  First, I could turn that warning into an error which would tell configure that `-ffast-math` isn't a valid option.  I would hope that when configure tries to add that to the commandline, it would then see it isn't able to and decide that maybe adding it was a bad idea after all ... The second option (which I don't think is quite as clean) is to just tell `icc` to silence that kind of warning ...

Responding to the comments, here's the relevant portion of `configure.ac`:

```
# add -ffast-math etc if possible
AX_CHECK_COMPILER_FLAGS([-ffast-math],
  [CFLAGS="$CFLAGS -ffast-math"
])

AX_CHECK_COMPILER_FLAGS([-mtune=native -march=native],
  [CFLAGS="$CFLAGS -mtune=native -march=native"
])
```

That m4 macro appears to have been taken from [here](https://github.com/alip/afprint/blob/master/m4/ax_check_compiler_flags.m4)

I suppose that fixing that to be smarter would be the "holy-grail" -- But as `icc` returns a successful exit status even when `-ffast-math` is passed (or `-mtune=native` etc.), I don't really think that there is too much that can be done there (feel free to prove me wrong).  that said, **I don't want to hard-code checks for intel into the configure script...**.  That seems overly messy.

Comment: Why not just fix the configure script?

Comment: You really don't want `-ffast-math`, even with gcc, unless you really really know what you're doing.

Comment: @PaulR -- That's not the part of the code I work on -- and I trust that the person responsible for the c-code really knows what he is doing -- he's a former linux kernel dev.  (I'm actually working on the fortran side of things which doesn't use `ffast-math`.  I'm just trying to silence as many of the warnings that don't pertain to my side of the code as possible).

Comment: @CarlNorum -- Sure.  I'll look for the relevant parts and include them in the question  (that's what I'd like to do).  But the configure script says -- "If I can use -ffast-math, lets do it!".  Unfortunately, when it tries to compile a program with `-ffast-math` using intel, it succeeds.

Comment: @CarlNorum -- Added relevant portions of configure script.  If you know how to fix them, I'd be delighted :)

Comment: I don't know much about ICC, but wouldn't adding `-Werror` or whatever the equivalent is to that `CFLAGS` line do it?

Comment: The `AX_*` macros are not standard already; the standard names start `AC_`.  So, you should look at the definition of the non-standard macros and make them detect the warnings as errors.  Maybe you need to add `-Werror` to the command line (that would work with GCC; I haven't got `icc` to try it out on).  Look at the output of `icc --help`; look at the `icc` manual.  But fix the configure script since the configure script is responsible for detecting the correct options and is failing in its duty.

Comment: @CarlNorum -- unfortunately, the code doesn't compile completely without warnings.  As that would turn every warning into an error, I think that would count out that solution

Comment: You only need to add `-Werror` while testing for the other options; not as a permanent addition to the command line.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler -- How do you make it detect a warning reliably in a compiler independent way?  All that configure can really go by is the exit status of the compiler when it tries something ...

Comment: @JonathanLeffler -- doesn't that impose that the compiler must have a `-Werror` option?

Comment: If you write the macro, you can look at the standard error of the compilation and detect 'unknown option' and decide that the option doesn't work.  If `icc` doesn't have `-Werror` or an equivalent option, you have to work harder to detect the mismatch, but the problem must be resolved by the configure script; that's what configure scripts do — sort out what is usable and what is not usable.  Your current configure script is defective so it needs fixing.  The `icc` compiler may be making its life harder, but that just means someone needs to do some work on the configure script.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler -- I would more submit that `icc` is defective for passing this through.  configure *must* rely on some conventions in order to be useful (e.g. non-zero exit status means success) -- and our program does compile successfully -- So I submit that `configure` is right in passing it through.

Comment: OK - then if the configure is correct, you can't complain about the warnings that the compiler generates.  Your call — the configure script is correct and the warnings are immaterial, or the warnings are material and the configure script is incorrect. (And the point of a configure script is to hide the peculiarities of different systems so that only the writers of the configure script have to worry about it, not the consumers.)  —OO—

Comment: I would argue that `-ffast-math` is not something the configure script should be setting at all.  Let the user add it to `CFLAGS` if it is desired.  Just remove the relevant sections from `configure.ac`.

Comment: @WilliamPursell -- I would argue that a dev is much more suited to making the decision about whether or not `-ffast-math` is appropriate for the code than a user.

Comment: @mgilson The maintainer is not capable of even knowing what compiler the user is using, and is not in a position to make such a decision.  "user" in this context is typically a package maintainer or a system admin who is familiar with the platform and fully capable of making such decisions.  At best, the maintainer could mention fast-math in a README.  Some might choose to add it via `AC_ARG_ENABLE`.

Comment: @WilliamPursell -- maintainer and/or devs are the *only* people who are capable of knowing whether a flag like `-ffast-math` causes the code to break.  I don't think that most of our users are capable of making that decision.

Comment: To clarify: "package maintainer" being the maintainer of a package management system and creating an rpm, deb, pkg, etc. from the source.

Comment: @WilliamPursell -- That is irrelevant for us.  Our code is a scientific code which is used by *scientists* and is re-built for each run that a scientist wants to do.  It will never be put into a package management system, but performance is critical.

Comment: @mgilson.  If a user (again, "user" here is typically a person who often wears the "developer" hat, but is at the moment building your software) is not capable of running `make check` to see that the build worked with `ffast-math`, then you haven't provided an adequate test suite.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24381/discussion-between-william-pursell-and-mgilson)

Comment: @WilliamPursell -- Over half of the code is written in fortran77 -- There isn't a reliable way to specify an exit status in F77, so that makes `make check` relatively worthless for that side of the code...

Comment: Your test suite does not need to rely on the return codes.  It should be validating the output.